# How do I access elements of a corpus and write to file in R?

Tags: r, nlp, rstudio, corpus

I am dealing with a vcorpus in R that looks like this: [image]

I to call content-> content and then content->meta-> id for each individual document.  I want to write just the content-> content and content->meta-> id to separate text files for each document later on.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to extract the elements you want, and then apply it to your corpus.

Something like this:

```
extractContentID <- function(x) {
  out <- list()
  out$content <- x$content
  out$id <- x$meta$id
  return(out)
}

newFiles <- sapply(Doc, extractContentID)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error in x$content : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: It looks like there may be an additional nesting in your Vcorpus which is covered by the little popup in the file you submitted. You could try:

sapply(Doc[[1]], extractContentID) in the last line.

But overall, the point is to write a general function which extracts the elements you want, and then use apply to use that function on each element in your corpus.